# iphone app hangs in AppDelegate (?)

Tags: iphone

No nib/IB, so I've inserted "myAppDelegate" in main and deleted the reference to main.xib in info.plist. Debug continues nicely through all five tab controllers; they seem to have gotten properly loaded into the nav controller.  In fact, control passes out of the last "}" in applicationDidFinishLaunching.  But there was no (visible) response back at [window addSubview:[tabBarController view]]; and [window makeKeyAndVisible]; statements, much less to the loadView within the first tab (program execution never gets there).  The last line is, UIApplication _performInitializationWithURL:sourceBundleID:].  I missed a step? I executed a step improperly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you create an `UIWindow` instance in `applicationDidFinishLaunching:`?

```
window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
```

Also, the line you call `UIApplicationMain` should look like this:

```
int retVal = UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, @"UIApplication", @"YourAppDelegate");
```

where YourAppDelegate is the name of your AppDelegate class.

Comment: Bingo!  I have no idea when I deleted the UIWindow alloc / init line, and no idea why that action ever would have seemed like a good idea. The code was present in earlier versions.  Thanks for the fresh pair of eyes! The app's working fine now.

Comment: You're welcome. Brainfart happens to all of us, just see my older answers for great examples =)

If you're satisfied with my answer, please mark it as accepted by clicking the tick mark on the left.